# Using Classes / OOP in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I'm pretty proficient with PHP, outside of OOP - which I am just now starting to jump in to.

I've been watching videos and reading tutorials, but they are all still pretty confusing...

If I have

**FILE 1 (class.time.php)**

```
class Time {
    function GetTime(){
        $time = date('H:i:s');
        printf($time);
    }
}
```

and then in a nother php page I've got

**FILE 2 (page.php)**

I can do

```
include('class.time.php');
```

and then anywhere in this page I can then do

```
$time = new Time; //Calling the class and setting the class to a variable
$time->GetTime(); //This is BASICALLY saying (run the 'GetTime' function in the 'Time Class'
```

My main question is, is the comment above (This is BASICALLY saying.....) correct? or is there a better way to think of it?

Comment: 1) Remember the ellipses. 2) I tend to phrase it - Creating a new Time object called $time... Calling $time's GetTime() method. 3) You're missing a closing bracket in `class.time.php`. Maybe you just didn't copy and paste it...

Comment: ^ Thanks for the explanation, as for 3 - I typed it on the go as a simple example, hence the missing bracket (though I DID just learn about making sure to include `()`.

Comment: You don't need to include `()` with the `new` operator, though you probably *should* as a matter of style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## regarding method calls

I would make one correction to your statement, hinting a little more accurately at what Object Orientation is all about. Your comment reads:

> run the 'GetTime' function in the 'Time Class'

Which is only kinda accurate, and expounding on it may clarify OOP for you. For the purposes of this post, I might rephrase it this way:

> run the 'GetTime' method (which is defined in the Time class) *bound to the object stored in $time*

See the difference? You aren't just calling a function from a class, you are saying "get the processing instructions from the class, but bind those instructions to this *specific* object and then execute.

It may sound like mincing words, but it's critical to understanding encapsulation. Objects of a class share their method definitions, but they **do not share data**.

You can think of an object as essentially a set of two things:

1. A block of memory holding it's own, personal data
2. A pointer to a set of methods with special access to that data

(the "special" nature of the methods' relationship to the data is either implicit or explicit, it's up to you)

The distinction is readily evident when you start using "member variables" (sometimes called "object properties", "instance variables (aka ivars)", or similar names). Consider this sample code:

```
class Person {
  public $name;
  public printName() {
    echo $this->name;
  }
}

$me = new Person();
$you = new Person();

$me->name = "Chris";
$you->name = "Alex";

$me->printName(); // "Chris"
$you->printName(); // "Alex"
```

This highlights the fact that each object has it's own memory for instance variables. They share the definition of those variables, as well as the blocks of code written to process those variables.

The special variable `$this` is of particular interest to my overall intention with this answer: the same variable in the same method definition actually points to a different object depending on which object you call the method on.

## regarding `new`

Now to the previous line, where your comment reads (in regard to `$time = new Time`):

> Calling the class and setting the class to a variable

The way I would phrase it is:

> Make an instance of this class, and allow me to access the instance through $time

That word, **instance** will be a big concept to get solid before moving on. You don't *call a class*, you *call a method*, and you don't (in PHP at least) set the value of variables to be a class, you set them to point to *instances* of the class. Sometimes people use the words *instance* and *object* interchangeably, which is fine. But you should not use them interchangeably with the word *class*.

**Let's get technical**:

When you use the `new` operator, technically you are telling PHP to do two things:

1. grab some fresh memory, *exactly enough* to store all the member variables defined in the class
2. call a special method on that new object to allow me to initialize my object

So if you call `new` twice, you grab enough memory for 2 objects, and so on. PHP uses your class definition to figure out how much memory to allocate for you, and find the special method to call.

That special method is called `__construct`, and is guaranteed to be called when your objects are created, with that special `$this` variable pointing to your shiny new memory. Here's a sample of how you might use it:

```
class Foo {
 private $createdTime;
 public function __construct() {
  $this->createdTime = time();
 }
}

$myFoo = new Foo;
```

Even though you don't see it, `__construct()` *was* called and the value of `$createdTime` was initialized.

Comment: The level of detail here is astounding. +1 and selected, thanks! I'll be looking forward to implementing some test environments, and the "me" and "you" examples are wonderfully simple and clear. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, but the syntax should be:

```
$time = new Time();
$time->GetTime();
```

(don't forget the parentheses, otherwise you are referring to class properties)

Also, it is a good idea to declare your methods as public, protected, or private. If you are going to call the GetTime method from outside the class, it would need to be public.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the 'public, protected, or private'? Or point to some documentation? I haven't seen that before

Comment: [Here](http://nefariousdesigns.co.uk/object-oriented-php-part-3-taking-relationships-further.html) you are.

Comment: Looks like mihir beat me to it. Bear in mind, access modifiers (public, protected, private) were added in php 5 - and to preserve backwards compatibility with php 4, any methods declared without an access modifier (like yours above) would default to public.

Comment: you really shouldn't still be using PHP4

Comment: The note about the parenthesis with the `new` operator is misleading; it is not necessary when your constructor does not need arguments. It's not that I consider it good style to omit them, but lets be fair (and utterly accurate): see the php docs foremost example of instantiation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Comment: ctrahey: "new" is the one that does the heavy work here, it really makes no difference whether or not you have parenthesis on the constructor if there are no parameters to be passed. Do whatever works for you, there's little point in nitpicking this point.

Comment: @Evan (note `@` so I get a ping ;-) I agree it's nitpicking for OP, but it was the essence of this answer and I wanted to be clear to OP that it is, indeed a (style) nitpick.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically your assumption is correct (apart from syntax errors).

However thats not a very good OO design.

Have a look at this, it give some good examples of OO design: http://www.math-cs.gordon.edu/courses/cs211/ATMExample/

Answer (score 0):

Since in this case "get time" will never change and accepts no parameters, you would do best to put this into a static method, since it's a waste to instantiate a class in this situation

eg:

```
class Time {
    static public function GetTime(){
        $time = date('H:i:s');
        printf($time);
    }
}

Time::GetTime(); // gets the time, no need to do $time = new Time();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you are doing it correct, but for using a simple built-in date function, using it via class would probably just over complicate it.

Following is an excellent article for learning OOP in PHP
[PHP OOP for beginners](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762)